# Unir campos de propia tabla en Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Estoy teniendo un problema que me trae de cabeza. Tengo una tabla TELEFONOS en Access con las columnas Prefijo_proveedor y Prefijo_cliente. Necesito (preferiblemente con conjuntos) encontrar los Prefijo_Proveedor que nunca son Prefijo_cliente. ¿Alguna idea?
Esto es lo que he intentado hasta el momento, pero no sé qué más hacer.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TELEFONOS INNER JOIN TELEFONOS_2
ON TELEFONOS.Prefijo_proveedor != TELEFONOS_2.Prefijo_cliente;
```

Comment: Bienvenido JP, te recomiendo leer [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) si todavía no lo haz echo, para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida debes agregar siempre que has intentado y porque no funciono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas entonces no es un inner join, si no una select anidada:

```
SELECT *
FROM TELEFONOS
WHERE Prefijo_Proveedor NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Prefijo_Cliente
                                FROM TELEFONOS)
```

Esto debe mostrarte los resultados esperados.

Saludos.

Comment: Me sale 0. Creo que es porque hay un null en Prefijo_Cliente.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de datos son las columnas?

Comment: Las columnas son ambas del tipo número.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un pantallazo con algunos de los valores que no deberían salir? En principio si las dos columnas son del mismo tipo debe mostrar los resultados adecuados. A menos que haya entendido mal lo que necesitas y lo que pides sea que te muestre los registros en los que el prefijo_proveedor y el prefijo_cliente es distinto.

Comment: La solución sólo requería algo de ayuda debido al Null. SELECT * FROM TELEFONOS WHERE Prefijo_Proveedor NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Prefijo_Cliente FROM TELEFONOS WHERE Prefijo_Cliente <> Null);

Comment: Me alegro entonces que guiado por mi respuesta hayas encontrado la solución.

Comment: Si ya tenéis la respuesta, por favor @JPBarroso, marca la respuesta como correcta, para que se cierre y aparezca como solucionada.